# React Typescript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

`**issue:  The expected type comes from property 'listing' which is declared here on type
'IntrinsicAttributes & ListingClientProps'**

I've tried many things but still not working

SafeListing and SafeUser are Types..
and I don't get why I'm getting error
can anyone help with that?

ListingClient.tsx

```
interface ListingClientProps {
   reservations?: SafeReservation[];
   listing: SafeListing & {
      user: SafeUser;
   };
   currentUser?: SafeUser | null;
}

const ListingClient: React.FC<ListingClientProps> = ({
   listing,
   currentUser,
   reservations = [],
}) => {
// rest of the code
}
```

page.tsx

```
import getCurrentUser from "@/app/actions/getCurrentUser";
import getListingById from "@/app/actions/getListingById";
import ClientOnly from "@/app/components/ClientOnly";
import EmptyState from "@/app/components/EmptyState";
import ListingClient from "./ListingClient";
import getReservations from "@/app/actions/getReservation";

interface IParams {
   listingId?: string;
}

const ListingPage = async ({ params }: { params: IParams }) => {
   const listing = await getListingById(params);
   const reservations = await getReservations(params);
   const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

   if (!listing) {
      return (
         <ClientOnly>
            <EmptyState />
         </ClientOnly>
      );
   }

   return (
      <ClientOnly>
         <ListingClient listing={listing} currentUser={currentUser} reservations={reservations} />
      </ClientOnly>
   );
};

export default ListingPage;
```

types.ts

```
import { Listing, Reservation, User } from "@prisma/client";

export type SafeListing = Omit<Listing, "createdAt"> & {
   createdAt: string;
};

export type SafeReservation = Omit<
   Reservation,
   "createdAt" | "startDate" | "endDate" | "listing"
> & {
   createdAt: string;
   startDate: string;
   endDate: string;
   listing: SafeListing;
};

export type SafeUser = Omit<User, "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "emailVerified"> & {
   createdAt: string;
   updatedAt: string;
   emailVerified: string | null;
};
```

`

ERORR MESSAGE

[{
"resource": "/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects_new/airbnb-clone/app/listings/[listingId]/page.tsx",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "2322",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Type '{ createdAt: string; user: { createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: (() => string) | null; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; id_token: string | null; }; ... 10 more ...; price: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Omit<{ id: string; title: string; description: string; imageSrc: string; createdAt: Date; category: string; roomCount: number; bathroomCount: number; guestCount: number; locationValue: string; userId: string; price: number; }, "createdAt"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.\n  Type '{ createdAt: string; user: { createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: (() => string) | null; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; id_token: string | null; }; ... 10 more ...; price: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ user: SafeUser; }'.\n    Types of property 'user' are incompatible.\n      Type '{ createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: (() => string) | null; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; id_token: string | null; }' is not assignable to type 'SafeUser'.\n        Type '{ createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: (() => string) | null; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; id_token: string | null; }' is not assignable to type '{ createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: string | null; }'.\n          Types of property 'emailVerified' are incompatible.\n            Type '(() => string) | null' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.\n              Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 27,
"startColumn": 25,
"endLineNumber": 27,
"endColumn": 32,
"relatedInformation": [
{
"startLineNumber": 49,
"startColumn": 4,
"endLineNumber": 49,
"endColumn": 11,
"message": "The expected type comes from property 'listing' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListingClientProps'",
"resource": "/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects_new/airbnb-clone/app/listings/[listingId]/ListingClient.tsx"
}
]
}]

Comment: Show the full error message

Comment: check, I've edited the post

Comment: The relevant code might not be posted. The root type error is `Types of property 'emailVerified' are incompatible.\n Type '(() => string) | null' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.` so the issue might be related to `SafeListing`

Comment: Your whole usage of omit and keys and taking an intersection with a type redefining them...appears kinda useless? It looks like you are trying to use a technique from nominally typed system to differentiate between validated and unsafe input, but TS is structurally typed, so if I do `type Unsafe { a: string, b: number }; type Safe = Omit<Unsafe, 'a'> & { a: string }` then I can still pass unsafe data to a function that is supposed to only accept validated sanitized input: the two are effectively identical types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved problem,

```
npx prisma db push
```

changed my prisma schema.